# How do I retrieve the date and time from DateTime string

Tags: c#, .net

How can I retrieve date and time from `DateTime` string?

```
DateTime datefrom = 8/27/2012 12:08:25 AM
```

I want to retrieve only the date into one variable and only the time (with AM/PM) into another variable.

I want something like this:

```
string date = 8/27/2012
string time = 12:08:25 AM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
    string date = dateform.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
    string time = dateform.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

MM - month
dd - day
yy - year, can also use yyyy if you want it with 4 numbers

hh - hour
mm - minute
ss - second
t - one letter as in AM -> A and PM - P
tt - two letters AM/PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Date and timeOfDay properties

```
//Date
dateform.Date;

//Time
dateform.TimeOfDay;
```

You can use ToString in order to format